# Dangerous mix Splash + Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

I have a Splash activity in which through intent I want the user to be redirected to different classes depending on whether it is the first time the app is accessed.

Other than being really slow, it crashes

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private long splashDelay = 1500;
    int counter;
    SharedPreferences app_preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 1);
        System.out.println("count is..." +counter);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                if(counter==1){
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Attempt.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, MainPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("counter", +(counter+1));
                editor.commit();
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
    }
}
```

basically the logcat goes on and on and the tops of the red wave states "Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {yo.laststage/yo.laststage.MainPage}"

Comment: The error indicates a problem with `MainPage`.

Comment: thanks Tynn. I had already checked the manifest and the layout (just a textview). What else could it be?

Comment: I mean, it looks like `MainPage` is stoped and not resumed before. Your code shows the `MainActivity`. There might be a problem in code you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

I had too much coding and simplified everything like this.
In case anyone was interested, what I wanted to achieve is having a SPLASH page in MainActivity.class and check whether it was the first time the app was run or not.
IF YES, the app redirects automatically to One.Class
ELSE (aka it's not the first time), it redirects automatically to Two.Class.

don't forget to declare your activities in Manifest

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

                Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);
                if (isFirstRun){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, One.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Two.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();




}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```